# WAP 2016 not sending client to ADFS properly

Tags: adfs

We are setting up on premises ADFS and WAP servers.

We are using a SSL cert shared between the SDFS server and WAP.
We are using split brain DNS so that the internal clients point to the ADFS server and the external users get routed to the WAP.
The ADFS service name is the external DNS name and is different than the host name.
The MVC web application has been published on the WAP.

Internal clients get routed to the ADFS server login page and get authenticated correctly. The external clients get routed to the login page but a TCP rst gets sent to the client immediately. I can't find any logs in the event viewer to help troubleshoot this. 
Can someone offer a suggestion?